# Google groups rendering ads over the top of the post I'm trying to read

Tags: browser, rendering, google-groups

I'm trying to read [this](http://groups.google.co.uk/group/microsoft.public.access.macros/browse_thread/thread/fe62f4d2eccc276e?pli=1) but Google's layout is rendering a menu and collection of text ads over the top left of the post so I can't read it.

Does anyone know how to fix this so I can see the content?

I've tried in both Firefox 3.5.1 and Internet Explorer 7 (this is a work machine so I can't upgrade to IE8)

[image]

Comment: Fine here from the UK on Chrome 2.0.172.43 & <shudder> IE6

Comment: And I just realised I forgot to obfuscate my gmail address in the screenie :-O

Be nice now peeps!

Comment: Renders fine in IE8 too. And about email: _I SHALL SPAM YOU TO DEATH_ >:E (kidding, but re-upload that image anyway, just in case) Btw, my email is just like yours... Entirely different, but exactly the same :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**SOLVED** But I'm still filing this under WTF

In Firefox, an F5 refresh re-rendered it correctly.

Tried the same in IE, remains the same.

*shrug*

Comment: The magic of F5, eh?

Answer (score 0):

Looks OK when I read it. What browser are you using? Try another one, like [Chrome](http://www.google.com/chrome) for example.

Comment: Just tried with Chrome. Same.

Comment: Wicked :\ (min15chars)

Answer (score 0):

I see a very clear page with firefox and a few extensions. What is your browser?
I opened up all my extensions and just got a few simple text ads on the right column.
Are you sure your browser does not have other things attached that are doing this?

<sub>(or, maybe the UK servers are giving you local content! There was some stuff earlier about UK servers restricting content for people outside the country -- BBC i think).</sub>

---

On firefox, install the `no-script` and `adblock-plus` addons,
And, try to see the page after a browser restart. 
You would need to subscribe for adblock rules
(a free service),
but, i think, just no-script should solve the problem if its site-based javascripts doing this.
Not, if its other browser addons/toolbars doing this.

---

No, I don't think you should need to install addons for such things.
Something is not right here.
 Even the lines do not match properly on the pic.
It looks like the Ad column is clipped and pasted on the left edge.
I am surprised to note that all browsers are doing this
(do you have a reference from another machine on your network?)

Comment: I get the simple text ads, but on the left instead of the right, just under the "About this group", "Subscribe to this group" etc.

Comment: @NiceGuy, ok, that is what I referred to. Your twitter pic suggests some rendering problem.

Comment: Should I *really* have to install a bunch of third party extensions to do this?  What if I didn't have firefox?  Its just plain weird that its happening in all 3 browsers on this machine

Comment: Even the lines do not match properly on the pic... it looks like the Ad column is clipped and pasted on the left edge.

Answer (score 0):

My solution was to select the text (dragging upwards with the mouse over the desired content), then copy it into Notepad, read it there, done!

I can reproduce the error using WinXP with Firefox 352 and IE7 -- appears in both.

I'm guessing this is caused by bad HTML in the ad or in the poster's name.